# Fetch XML value from one column and update it in another column

Tags: sql-server

I Have a table like below. Need to fetch the Fname value from the column MyXml and update in the column MyVal. Is it possible without looping the rows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(MyXml xml, MyVal nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @test
Values(N'<Name>
            <Fname>A</Fname>
            <Lname>AAA</Lname>
        </Name>',''),
        (N'<Name>
            <Fname>B</Fname>
            <Lname>BBB</Lname>
        </Name>','')

UPDATE @test
SET
    MyVal = MyXml.value('(Name/Fname/.)[1]','nvarchar(max)')

SELECT *
FROM @test t
```